# returning error when execvp does not find program

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, exec

```
int spawn( char* program, char** args) {

pid_t child_pid;
child_pid = fork(); 

if( child_pid > 0) {  /
        wait(NULL);
        return (int)child_pid;
}

else {
    if(execvp(program, args) == -1){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    return (int)child_pid; 
    }
}
```

I know this code is kind of messy but please bear with me: I'm trying to create my own shell. This is the function that will spin up a new child process and execute the code. However, I am unable to return an error when I type in a string.

For example, if I type 'heyman' I just get 'heyman' back while I'd like to get some sort of error ('heyman' is not a command) back.

I was hoping the exit(EXIT_FAILURE) would do that but it has not. Would appreciate if anyone could help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `perror()` to report the error.

```
if (execvp(program, args) == -1) {
    perror("execvp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

There's no need to use `return (int)child_pid` in the child function. If `execvp()` succeeds, none of the code after it runs; if it fails, you report the error and exit.

Comment: That worked. Can you tell me how you knew that or where you found that from? I'd like to know a source I can use for linux programming rather than constantly asking questions

Comment: Where I learned about `perror()`? I don't remember, I've known about it for over 20 years. Any decent Unix programming textbook should have it.